# C++ http read special characters from my SQL DB

Tags: c++, sql, http, utf-8, special-characters

when I perform a POST call from my C++ client fetching MySQL data (I use a classical webservice), I got troubles when special characters are in the http result, eg "è", "à", "ò"...
In fact, I store the server answer (the http result) in a char* variable where I can read "Ã¨" instead of "è". This is for the POST:

```
HttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
HttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
HttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");
HttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
HttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "it-IT");
HttpObject->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"); 

HttpObject->Post(MY_WEBSERVICE, MY_TEXT, TEXT_length, CALLBACK_GotHeaders, NULL);
```

And this is for the return:

```
char buf[HTTP_Buffer];
snprintf(buf, HTTP_Buffer, http_result);
```

I also tried another type of experiment: I wrote the whole string result as I wish in a .txt file. I put the file on my server and I fetch it using a GET, to read the text from my C++ client. In this case, I rightly read all the characters without problems. 
So, I suppose, there is something strange in the SQL result, but I'm not able to fix it.
There should be something in the charset used by my client and the SQL DB.

The strings are saved on the DB as NVARCHAR.
My client use a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: a) what's the point in specifying anything except UTF-8 in Accept-Charset?

b) it sounds you're getting UTF-8 back, so what's the problem?

Comment: Well ("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3") was in an example I found somewhere and I supposed this would tell "use ISO-8859-1 and utf-8 as charset". For the b) point, my trouble is related to the wrong encoding from the SQL DB (where I can properly use "è") and the return of my http post where instead of "é" I got "Ã¨".